# How can I force autoindex and ignore index.html files

Tags: nginx, mod-autoindex

When nginx serves a directory with autoindex, it will list files, but when index.html exists, the browser will load that file. I want it to ignore it.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name herbert;

    location / {
        root /srv/www;
        index index.htm index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        expires 300s;
    }

    location /site-dumps/ {

        root /srv/www/;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `index nonexistent-file;` in `location`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You should move other files in other directory and create an iframe in index.html.

Something like that:

**index.html**

```
<iframe src="/site-dumps_files"></iframe>
```

**nginx.cnf**

```
server {
      listen      80;
      server_name herbert;

      location / {
        root /srv/www;
        index index.htm index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        expires 300s;
      }

      location /site-dumps/ {
        root /srv/www/;
      }

      location /site-dumps_files/ {
        root /srv/www/;
        autoindex on;
      }
}
```

I hope it useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;

 server_name localhost;

 autoindex on;
 index =404;
 
 location / {
   root /path_to_www_dir;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put: `index main.html main.htm;` instead of `index index.htm index.html;`